# Java - Execute SQL queries only once

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, spring-data

I'm developing a J2EE application with Spring framework and MySQL database. I want to execute the SQL script from java (probably with a request mapping) only once. I have store the sql statements in a properties file as a key-value pair and I loop through each key and execute the statement.

```
    Connection con = ds.getConnection();
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();

    Enumeration enuKeys = properties.keys();
    while (enuKeys.hasMoreElements()) {
        String key = (String) enuKeys.nextElement();
        String value = properties.getProperty(key);
        stmt.execute(value);
    }
```

Is this the correct way of doing? or is there any other way doing the same? Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

As mentioned in the comment, I tried Spring jdbc intialize database but it is not executing all the queries in the sql file. Only the first 'create' query is executed successfully and it throws an execption "Table 'table_name' already exists". Other queries in the .sql file is not executed. This happens every time I run the server. Kindly help

Comment: I think a stored sql procedure can help you. Did you check it?

Comment: Keeping the sql statements in a properites might not be a good way. Its better to have it as a procedure. For example, if you have insert sql statement, put it into procedure, call it.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-intializing-datasource might be worth a read

Comment: I will not have "insert" queries in the property file. Only the one time activity like creating table or database. I will run this in different environment when it is needed.

Comment: @RC Thanks for your quick reply. Seems to be very useful. How I need to place the queries inside the .sql file in order to work?

Comment: The sql file is executed as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the sound of it you're trying to setup database schema when your code starts and one of the statement couldn't be run because the table already exist. You need to use statements that checks beforehand (eg: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`) or catch the exception after executing each statement so it can proceed to the next one.

```
try {
  stmt.execute(value);
} catch (Exception e) {
  //.. raise some warning and continue ..
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I re-visited my statement and added IF NOT EXISTS. Now everything works fine.